# How to import the content of my text file into a ListView and save it in a table

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, wpf

I've been working on this for so long and I haven't really found the answer yet.

What I want to do is import the content of my TimeLog.txt file and display it into a ListView, then save it in my database.

This is the content of my TimeLog.txt file:

```
No  Mchn    EnNo        Name        Mode    IOMd    DateTime    
00001   1   00001234                1   0   2004/01/01  01:01
00002   1   00001234                1   0   2015/05/12  04:01
00003   1   00001234                2   0   2015/05/12  04:01
00004   1   00001234                1   0   2004/01/01  01:01
00005   1   00001234                1   0   2015/05/13  10:42
00006   1   00001234                2   0   2004/01/01  01:01
00007   1   00000001                1   0   2004/01/01  01:01
00008   1   00000002                1   0   2004/01/01  01:01
00009   1   00000001                1   0   2004/01/01  01:01
00010   1   00000001                1   0   2004/01/01  01:01
00011   1   00000001                1   0   2004/01/01  01:01
00012   1   00000002                1   0   2004/01/01  01:01
00013   1   00000001                1   0   2004/01/01  01:01
```

My codes look like this:
namespace textfile
{

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(@"TimeLog\GLG_001.txt"))
        {
            var listViewItem = new ListViewItem();
            listViewItem.Content = line;

            ListView.Items.Add(listViewItem);
        }


    }
}
```

}

Badly need your help.

Comment: It's a complex work. You should split it into simple problems and then try to solve them one by one and then ask if you have some trouble with a particular step in the process.

Answer (score 2):

1) You should create class to hold data from the each line of file:

```
class TimeLogData
{
    public string NoMchn { get; set; }
    public int EnNo { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Mode { get; set; }
    public int IOMd { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}
```

2) You should create class which convert single line from file into class `TimeLogData`:

```
class TimeLogLineParser
{
    public TimeLogData ParseLine(string line)
    {
        TimeLogData result = null;
        var tmp = line.Split(new[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (tmp.Length == 7)
        {
            result = new TimeLogData
            {
                NoMchn = tmp[0],
                EnNo = Convert.ToInt32(tmp[1]),
                Name = tmp[2],
                Mode = Convert.ToInt32(tmp[3]),
                IOMd = Convert.ToInt32(tmp[4]),
                Time = Convert.ToDateTime(tmp[5] + " " + tmp[6])
            };
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

3) You should read each line of file, convert this line into object `TimeLogData` and add it to `List` of `TimeLogData`:

```
var data = new List<TimeLogData>();
var lineParser = new TimeLogLineParser();
foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(@"...path to your file..."))
{
    if (line.StartsWith("NoMchn")) continue;
    var objTmp = lineParser.ParseLine(line);
    if (objTmp != null) data.Add(objTmp);
}
```

4) Now you can use data list to binding items to `ListView` and insert data into SQL Server.

Comment: I really appreciate your help a lot. I mean, I'm just a totally newbie in C# WPF and I dont have any idea on how to read text files(parsing).
In your step #2, can you help me with that one? Thanks!

Comment: @AdrianoHernandezIII what is the column separator in your file?

Comment: It's just a space. I have 7 columns.
But in a listview, ofcourse, it will be gridlines. help me with this one plssss..

Comment: @AdrianoHernandezIII space is not the best separator in your case (your last column have space in data and it's not the next column). The best separator is 'tab' or ';'. In #2 you should use string `Split` method and populate properties in `TimeLogData` class. Here is example how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668101/parse-line-of-text

Comment: i really cant change the structure of the content of the text file because it's generated by a biometric device.

Comment: @AdrianoHernandezIII ok, I mentioned about separator because you need remember about last column with date.

Comment: I really don't know how to parse those line of texts in your step number 2. If you could just help me with that one. Pls

Comment: I really cant understand the 2nd step. :(

Comment: @AdrianoHernandezIII check my answer again :)

Comment: Isn't it that binding only works if i have a model? In this case I dont have a model, instead I have a class. What will I do?

Comment: Your model in this case is class TimeLogData, you should read about MVVM :-)